# Gentoo "profile" definitions?

Tags: linux, command-line, compiling, gentoo, wiki

I'm using the Pentoo installer and it's asking me to select a profile.

[image]

I believe the "amd64" profile will compile software from source. The "binary" profile will instead use precompiled binaries created by the Pentoo developers. And the "bleeding_edge" option will compile from the upstream project? (i think)

My question is: **is there a wiki or manual (command line tool) I can view to better understand how Gentoo/Pentoo profiles work?** I'm looking for something that really details what each profile is and how it affects the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The general concept of a portage 'profile' in Gentoo is essentially equivalent to the concept of having separate Server, Desktop, and IoT installation images in other distributions, though it's not quite as obvious in Pentoo because they have a really limited set of profiles they provide and support.

In short, your selected profile at minimum dictates:

- What the default USE flags for some packages are.
- What packages are masked by default (and thus can't be installed without special configuration).

Depending on the specifics, it may also control:

- What packages are part of the `@system` package set (and therefore are included as implicit dependencies of everything on the system).
- Certain other aspects of portage configuration.

---

With Pentoo, the profile selection is pretty simple:

- The regular profile for your hardware (in your case `pentoo/default/linux/amd64`) will use what the developers consider stable versions of software, and build all updates locally.  If you can't decide, this is probably what you want.
- The `bleeding_edge` profile will instead use the newest versions of software available that are not know to actually break the system.  This most likely sets the appropriate `~*` keyword for your hardware in the global portage configuration.

The third option, labelled `binary` is the odd one here, because the name is actually kind of ambiguous.  I've not found any conclusive documentation myself on it, but I've also not searched exhaustively for it either.  My guess would be that your assessment is correct and it fetches pre-built packages from some central server instead of building them locally.

Comment: It appears that you are correct about the `binary` option. [This talk from Defcon14's wireless village](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGtIUdzADn4&t=6m1s) by Pentoo's author says exactly that. The posted link is timestamped.